# Questions about ScreenManager Kivy - how import multiples kv files

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have an ongoing project about personal finance and I intend to implement it with a Python application with Kivy, but I'm having problems with structuring and importing the screens. I want to have an organization for future maintenance, dividing each kv file into a different folder, without merging it into a single kv file, I know it's possible because I've seen a video and a code where the guy did it that way but I couldn't understand how it works. Can anyone give me a light on how I could make these internationals with ScreenManager?

Structure MAIN APPLICATION FOLDER: FinanceAPP/Screens/all folders with screen names/inside each folder the file referring to the screen.

Python version: 3.10.9
Kivy Version: 2.2.1
KivyMD Version: 1.1.1

I've tried in several ways the path and screenmanager of a single file but I couldn't

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)